# cannot resolve method mGoogleApiClient

Tags: java, android

why error mGoogleApiClient? 
this my gradle :

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.4'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.4'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

and this my source code :

```
@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
    LocationRequest mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
    }
}
```

Comment: show your whole gradle app file

Answer (score 1):

Because you haven't created the object
`mGoogleApiClient` Check the docs properly and create it before using it.

```
GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
         .addApi(LocationServices.API)
         .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
         .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
         .build()
```

Docs: https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi